# Does any version of Delphi warn about unbalanced if-else indentation?

Tags: delphi, if-statement, compiler-warnings

I edited some Delphi 6 code from

```
if functionA then 
else procedureB
```

into

```
if functionA then
  if testC then procedureD
else procedureB
```

instead of the correct

```
if functionA then
  begin
  if testC then procedureD
  end
else procedureB
```

If the compiler had warned me the connected if-else wasn't equally indented I would have realized my error at compile time.  Note that the correct code takes the "else" branch and calls procedureB only if functionA isn't true.  The wrong code takes the "else" only if functionA is true and testC is false.

Even if the original was

```
if not functionA then procedureB
```

I might have edited it into the wrong version.

Does any version of Delphi warn about unbalanced if-else indentation?

Comment: Why not use a formatter?

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know that you meant `if function then begin if testC then procedured end` instead of what you actually wrote? There are no psychic compilers currently, AFAIK. If you can find a compiler that can read a developer's mind and determine the intent between two syntactically correct blocks of code, let me know, and I'll invest a lot of money in it.  Learn to properly format your code. If you're working with legacy code that isn't properly formatted, use a formatter.. JEDI has an OS one, and recent IDE versions include them.)

Comment: The only thing that can help you is a code formatter...GExperts has one...and there's a JEDI code formatter...Remember to the compiler...white space is ignore...this is legal                                                                                                         if functionA then if testC then procedureD else procedureB

Comment: @KenWhite This is why I'm a big fan of significant indentation as used by, for instance, Python. Since we all read and write our code using the indentation to indicate structure, we may as well bake it into the language so that code and compiler are on the same page.

Comment: Just as a side note for completeness' sake: also valid is `if functionA then if testC then procedureD else` **`else`** `procedureB;`

Comment: @Uli: Why not let the compiler warn?  A formatter is an extra step and I'd still have to manually/visually catch the error.

Comment: @Witness Because formatters are available while the compiler isn't able to do what you want. ;-)

Comment: @KenWhite: By warning the if-else isn't even, the compiler warns me of my error. I don't need a "psychic", I just want another warning in the spirit of all the other warnings available (it doesn't "read my mind" but those warnings catch a lot of my errors). If "learn to properly format" means "make sure to remember to insert begin-end" then a formatter isn't going to help. If it means "make sure everything after your insert is consistently indented" then a formatter will do that but I'll still have to notice what changed to catch the bug, and I'd rather just get an automatic warning.

Comment: @HouseOfDexter: The "only" current thing that can help might be a formatter, but a new warning would be better.  Technically, it's not white space that's ignored (otherwise ifathenbelsec would be legal), it's *extra* white space that's ignored, but only by the compiler.  To the programmer, indentation implies a lot, so it would be nice if the compiler helped check that.

Comment: The problem with that warning is *there's nothing to warn about*, because the **code is correct**. Why litter with warnings about code that is correct? It creates noise and clutter, can obscure real issues, and it's a waste of time. If you properly indent your code, you can see where you should have a `begin..end` block, and if you make sure you use one anywhere there might be doubt or confusion you won't have this problem. I've *never* had it, because I indent correctly so I can see the code flow, and my rule is: add begin..end for anything longer than a single statement after an if, always.

Comment: @KenWhite: there **IS** something to warn about, because although the code is **syntactically** correct, a bug has been introduced, which can be warned about because the if-else aren't aligned. Why use warnings? Because they find mistakes, even though the code compiles. Feel free to turn off warnings, but I like them. Yes, **if** I always properly indent, & **if** I remember to use begin/end, & **if** I remember to avoid all other mistakes, I won't have a problem, but somehow I can't seem to reach that level of perfection, so I prefer if compiler warns me about anything it finds suspicious...

Comment: No, I turn on *all* hints and warnings, and work diligently on my code to eliminate them, which is why I don't want extraneous *non-warnings* cluttering my messages window. There's nothing suspicious in the code you posted until the compiler gets those psychic abilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does any version of Delphi warn about unbalanced if-else indentation?

No.

This is the reason why in my code base I never use single statements and always use compound statements.

```
if someBool then begin
  DoStuff;
end else begin
  DoOtherStuff;
end;
```

Comment: This is why I've heard of some Delphi developers argue that *all* `if`/`else` constructs should use `begin`/`end`, even if there is only a single statement inside.

Comment: @afrazier That's the house rule at my work. But then we came to Delphi from Modula-2.

Comment: It is a matter of style, but I always use begin...end blocks precisely because of these confusing issues and the risks involves with coming back to it later. If you want to produce deposable code then I suppose the short form is OK. For real code that needs to be maintained - it is not (in my opinion). In terms of indentation Castallia and Delphi 10 Seattle show begin/end indentations by using coloured lines, and this could be a big help with misaligned blocks but not in the above example.

Comment: I don't like this style because the if-else's aren't aligned and therefore more difficult to match up, superfluous begin-end and unaligned if-else start to really clutter things when you have nested if's, and later inserting an else-if means editing within a line (which I don't like to do) compared to editing between lines (which I prefer).  I'd probably prefer the example of Stijn of always including a null else when inserting an if-then instead of always including a begin-end.

Comment: ...so my acceptance is simply for your "no" answer.

Comment: It's clearly up to you how you format your code. It's a very personal matter. FWIW my 800kloc project has used this rule for 15 years with not a single mistake of this nature.

Comment: As for the null else, I don't thing that style is at all prevelant